# The transfer of the variable to the query Pentaho

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration, data-integration

I have job where I want to transfer max_id with query to other query.

[image]

In table input I have query

```
select max(uid) from table_1
```

in Set Variables I have

[image]

And I want to transfer variables to other table

[image]

In Table Input I have query:

```
select * from table2 where uid BETWEEN 407043 and ${MAX_UID}
```

But it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don’t need the Get Variables step. Just use that query and don’t forget to check the “replace variables in script” box.